# How can I position another image relative to the upper image

Tags: html, css, image, position

I have this shadow and I got a picture that needs to be in the same position as the square in the shaodw. I tried different things with Css. But always when I am resizing the window the picture is not in the same spot anymore compared to the shadow.

[Shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LCz9.jpg)

This is the desired result:
[Image with shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juvKR.png)

I already tried something like this with CSS:

```css
.product__image{

        max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.product__background{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    left: -35%;
    right: -100%;
    top: -20%;
    bottom: -10%;
    z-index: -1;

}
```

```html
<div class="product__image">
                <div class="product__background" style="background-image:
                    url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0050/5141/6625/files/pink.jpg?5067');" style="z-index: -100">
                </div>
                <img src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: '630x420'}}" class=""
                                    alt="Product image">

            </div>
```

But that didn't work with resizing the window.

Can someone help me to get this functionality?
I can't insert the shadow manually because then the shadow would also appear on other spots on the website.

Maybe there is a css option to generate this shadow. That would also be great!